# Python pygame not installing

Tags: python, pygame

C:\Users\matth>pip3 install pygame
Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [80 lines of output]

```
  WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
  Using WINDOWS configuration...

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
      h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1282, in request
      self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
      self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
      self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
      self.send(msg)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 975, in send
      self.connect()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1454, in connect
      self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
      return self.sslsocket_class._create(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
      self.do_handshake()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
      self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g18yr5c2\pygame_2c1b94c764cc404881a71cf0ac51d63e\setup.py", line 359, in <module>
      buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
    File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g18yr5c2\pygame_2c1b94c764cc404881a71cf0ac51d63e\buildconfig\config.py", line 225, in main
      deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g18yr5c2\pygame_2c1b94c764cc404881a71cf0ac51d63e\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 497, in main
      and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g18yr5c2\pygame_2c1b94c764cc404881a71cf0ac51d63e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 290, in ask
      update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
    File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g18yr5c2\pygame_2c1b94c764cc404881a71cf0ac51d63e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 273, in update
      download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
    File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g18yr5c2\pygame_2c1b94c764cc404881a71cf0ac51d63e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 124, in download_prebuilts
      download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
    File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g18yr5c2\pygame_2c1b94c764cc404881a71cf0ac51d63e\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 54, in download_sha1_unzip
      response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
      response = self._open(req, data)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
      result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
      return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.193.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
      raise URLError(err)
  urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:992)>
  Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
  Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip ed561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da

  ---
  For help with compilation see:
      https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
  To contribute to pygame development see:
      https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
  ---

  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 43):

**New answer (Feb 2023)**

`pip install pygame-ce`
^ pygame-ce (pygame community edition) is a modern fork of pygame by many pygame contributors that supports 3.11 out of the box, just recently launched. See https://github.com/pygame-community/pygame-ce/tree/main

**Short answer**

`pip install pygame --pre` is necessary right now due to your Python version

**Long answer**

Your traceback shows you are using Python 3.11, which was just released earlier today. Pygame is a "C extension" and needs to re-release itself with new "wheels" (binaries) for every new minor release of Python (3.9, 3.10, 3.11, etc.)

The latest "full" pygame release, 2.1.2, was released a while back and doesn't come with wheels for 3.11, so your system tries to build pygame from source. It fails to do so, because you don't have a pygame development environment set up.

However, the latest pre release of pygame, 2.1.3.dev8 (released recently) has wheels for 3.11, so your system will not need to compile pygame from source.

Once pygame 2.1.3 is released, this extra flag (which tells it to look for pre releases), won't be necessary.

Comment: Ah, gotcha thanks. Of course the day I want to try out a Pygame tutorial is the day 3.11 was released.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using poetry. Do the following:

```
poetry add pygame=2.1.3.dev8
```

If you are using pip. Do the following:

```
pip install pygame --pre
```

Comment: Now Jan14 and still no pygame for 3.11. I spent an hour trying to nest up the sdl dependencies. Please add a warning when you install on newer python.

Answer (score 0):

Install python 3.10 and wait for pygame to be ready for 3.11 and then install pygame for that version. You can also have 2 version of python installed.

To work with each one use:

py -3.10 script.py

py -3.11 script.py