# Pygame error "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully."

Tags: python, installation, pip, pygame

Hello i'm new in python and i try to install Pygame but i have an error

```
 × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]


      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
```

I have python 3.11, checked for update of pip, update of setuptools , and followed tuto and multiple topic but nothing work i have again and again this error. Can somebody help me?

things on tuto and topics about installing errors

Comment: Please show us the full text of the error. The command you ran and all those 77 lines of output.

Comment: I’m fairly confident this is the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188013/python-pygame-not-installing and it’s a Python 3.11 issue.

Comment: the topic you have linked work, pygame succesfully installed thanks