# How do I fix a metadata error on my mac terminal after trying to install pygame using python 3.11.0?

Tags: python, pip, pygame, metadata

Recently I had a problem with my computer (permission issues) and had to get my computer reset, meaning I need to reinstall pygame. When I try to install pygame (using pip) I get the following error.

```
name]=@dhcp-133-143 ~ % pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [31 lines of output]
      
      
      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using Darwin configuration...
      
      /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
      /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
      /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/8k/tc80k7710czdxlkx3y3z1jhh0000gn/T/pip-install-yi5cifen/pygame_c0921b1ceb304676bfd314c918f4dbc2/setup.py", line 359, in <module>
          buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
        File "/private/var/folders/8k/tc80k7710czdxlkx3y3z1jhh0000gn/T/pip-install-yi5cifen/pygame_c0921b1ceb304676bfd314c918f4dbc2/buildconfig/config.py", line 225, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/8k/tc80k7710czdxlkx3y3z1jhh0000gn/T/pip-install-yi5cifen/pygame_c0921b1ceb304676bfd314c918f4dbc2/buildconfig/config_darwin.py", line 132, in main
          [DependencyProg('SDL', 'SDL_CONFIG', 'sdl2-config', '2.0', ['sdl'])],
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/8k/tc80k7710czdxlkx3y3z1jhh0000gn/T/pip-install-yi5cifen/pygame_c0921b1ceb304676bfd314c918f4dbc2/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 39, in __init__
          self.ver = config[0].strip()
                     ~~~~~~^^^
      IndexError: list index out of range
      
      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

How do I fix this error so I can install pygame on my computer.
I have seen other people post about this error while using python 3.10 but none of the solutions seem to work for my computer. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice. Thanks. Also I am aware there have been other people asking similar questions however like I said none of the solutions worked for me. They all resulted in the same error.

I tried the following commands `pip install pygame`, `pip3 install pygame`,`py -m pip install pygame` (and most variations using py and -m)

All of these commands result with the same metadata error. I am using the most recent version of python (I think).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%2Fbin%2Fsh%3A+sdl2-config%3A+command+not+found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74188087/2221001 may help out. Knowing what version of python you are running would be step 1 though. `python --version` would solve that question.

Comment: Im using python 3.11.0

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me! pip install pygame --pre