# Why am i getting this error when i am trying to install pygame through cmd and pip?

Tags: python, windows, pygame

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User>py -3.10 -m pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]


      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...

   
output in image attached


      [end of output]



  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

C:\Users\User>
```

also tried just using pip install pygame, but keep getting the same error. Using windows 10 pro. Here is an image of all the errors i got [errors ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhV1Z.png)

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but according to their website you should install pygame in the user directory. So: `py -3.10 -m pip install -U pygame --user`

Comment: Thanks for trying, doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you try upgrading pip? `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: none of these worked :(, thanks tho

Comment: I sometimes get something similar. Updating all pip packages does it for me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip). Not sure how you do it in CMD on windows though

Comment: It’s this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188013/python-pygame-not-installing