# pygame won't install in the terminal

Tags: python, pygame

When trying to install pygame, (pip install pygame),Im getting the error:

** error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [77 lines of output]
**

(Im running Windows 11)

[I think everything is updated to the newest release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUQzr.png)

Ive tried updating everything, Ive tried updating my device, I have no idea what to do, any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: Pygame is not available yet for Python 3.11.

Comment: You are showing us the error summary only. There should be a more accurate error message earlier.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74188013/python-pygame-not-installing/74188087#74188087  you can use Python 3.11 with the latest pygame pre release

Answer (score -1):

Try running command prompt as admin. All you do is press the windows key, search "command prompt", and select to run it as an admin. Then just type the command. I don't know if this will work for you, but it always works for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, ramming things through as Administrator should _not_ be your first troubleshooting step.

Comment: regardless, running as an administrator, unfortunately, didn't help. Do you have any other ideas?